# Suppose $a,b,m$ are integers and $(a,m) = 1$. Does $a \equiv b \pmod m \Rightarrow (b,m) = 1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Suppose $a,b,m$ are integers and $(a,m) = 1$. Does $a \equiv b \pmod m \Rightarrow (b,m) = 1$ ?

I know the least residues of $a$ and $b$ are the same. And I know $$(m,a)=(a, a \mod m)$$, so the least residue of $a$ is relatively prime to $m$. But $$b = qm + a \mod m$$ and $$(b,m) = (m, b \mod m) = (m, a \mod m) = 1$$

Is this correct ? Is there an easier way to show this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(a,m)=1\Rightarrow \exists x,y\in \mathbb Z : ax+my=1$

Also given that $a \equiv b (\operatorname{mod} m)\Rightarrow \exists k\in \mathbb Z:a=mk+b$

Thus we have $x(mk+b)+my=1\Rightarrow bx+m(kx+y)=1\Rightarrow (b,m)=1$

Comment: Nice ! This is way more elegant than my approach. Could you tell me if my "proof" is correct too ?

Comment: looks fine to me

Comment: Most Welcome @AndreasLykkeIversen

Answer (score 2):

Since $a=b+mt$ for some $t$, every common divisor of $b$ and $m$ must also divide $a$. Since the only common divisor of $a$ and $m$ is $1$, the only common divisor of $b$ and $m$ is $1$.

More generally, this argument proves that if $a\equiv b \bmod m$ then the set of common divisors of $a$ and $m$ is the same as the set of common divisors of $b$ and $m$ . In particular, $\gcd(a,m)=\gcd(b,m)$.